# Trying to get Vue-heatmapjs working on a nuxt application

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

Hello first time posting on stack overflow so sorry
I am trying to get vue-heatmapjs https://github.com/BrockReece/vue-heatmapjs to work in my nuxt js project. Since i don't have a main.js I've put it in a plugin and I don't recieve any errors. the scroll map for this project seems to work however its simply the click map.

```js
plugins: [
    { ssr: false, src: "~plugins/heatmap-plugin.js"}
  ],
```

```js
import vue from 'vue'
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import Vueheatmap from 'vue-heatmapjs'

const stream = new Subject();
export const pauser = new Subject();

vue.config.productionTip = false;
vue.use(Vueheatmap, {
  stream,
  pauser,
  heatmapPreload: [{ x: 50, y: 50, value: 100 }],
  afterAdd(data) {
    console.log(data)
    // you can fire this back to your analytics server
  },
});

stream.subscribe(console.log);
```

Above is my plugin code

Comment: *the scroll map for this project seems to work however its simply the click map.* so it's working? what not?

Comment: Yeah the scroll map updates fine and changes colour based on where the user is however I can't get the heatmap to respond to any mouse or click movements so it never changes colour except for the test preload i have.

Comment: It's split between `v-scrollmap` (for scrolling heatmap), and `v-heatmap` (for the click and mouse movement heatmap), perhaps you only added v-scrollmap. Can you show how you're using it?

Comment: code for the demo is here https://github.com/BrockReece/vue-heatmapjs/blob/master/src/App.vue

Comment: I am only using the v-heatmap atm using
```<template lang="pug">
.list-and-filters-area(v-heatmap="true")
```

Comment: I don't have the pauser imported on the page Im testing perhaps that could be it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So After alot of searching its because the Dependancies for this heatmap app weren't compatible with our current nuxt and vue setup so I had set it all up again and change the dependancies and rewrite alot of the code.

Vue-rx is one of the keys i had to install aswell as update rxjs